# Neo4j PlugIn prevents database startup

Tags: logging, plugins, neo4j, user-defined-functions

I've developed a Neo4j PlugIn which works for end users. But one user had a problem I cannot explain. His Neo4j Install (Enterprise v 4.5.5) including APOC and GDS plugins works okay. But then he adds the Graphs for Genealogists plugin and it's whitelisting in the config file and the database fails to start. The debug file message is at the link below. I cannot see a fix in it and would appreciate input from others about it.

[debug.log](https://blobswai.blob.core.windows.net/gfg/debug.log)

Comment: The problem is with the updated v 4.5.5. When I set up a new project with 4.5.7 the plug in does not block the startup and it's functions can be listed in the Neo4j Browser but the database will not open in a standard browser and functions will not run because of an authentication problem. In Maven there is an error: package org.neo4j.driver is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/neo4j/driver/Session;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248) ~[?:?]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.FieldInjections.setters(FieldInjections.java:60) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileFunction(ProcedureCompiler.java:315) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileFunction(ProcedureCompiler.java:133) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:123) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:96) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.start(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:371) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.driver.Session
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248) ~[?:?]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.FieldInjections.setters(FieldInjections.java:60) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileFunction(ProcedureCompiler.java:315) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileFunction(ProcedureCompiler.java:133) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:123) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:96) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.start(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:371) ~[neo4j-procedure-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    ... 8 more
```

It seems one of the procedures is trying to use the Java Driver for Neo4j but the runtime does not have this dependency available. I will assume this is part of the plugin you authored.

I see two options:

1. make sure to include the Java Driver classes when you package your plugin (with maven-shade-plugin for instance)
2. since the plugin is running on the server side, you do not really need the Java driver at all. You can get a `GraphDatabaseService` as a field annotated with `@Context` on your procedure class and execute Cypher queries from there.

Comment: It was #2 ... I had the driver as provided in the pom file. Removng this allowed the database to start..  Thanks!!